# How can I safely solve this Java context classloader problem?

Tags: java, classloader, contextclassloader

One and only one of my hundreds of users has trouble starting my Java desktop app. It only starts for him about one-third of the time. The other two-thirds of the time a NullPointerException is thrown at startup:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:394)
    at javax.swing.JEditorPane.registerEditorKitForContentType(JEditorPane.java:1327)
    at javax.swing.JEditorPane.registerEditorKitForContentType(JEditorPane.java:1309)
    at javax.swing.JEditorPane.loadDefaultKitsIfNecessary(JEditorPane.java:1387)
    at javax.swing.JEditorPane.getKitTypeRegistry(JEditorPane.java:1344)
    at javax.swing.JEditorPane.getEditorKitClassNameForContentType(JEditorPane.java:1340)
    at javax.swing.JTextPane.<init>(JTextPane.java:76)
    at myapp.Launcher$1.run(Launcher.java:13)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:633)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

I've followed the stack trace to find that the cause is that

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
```

in JEditorPane is returning null.

Googling reveals that this is a sporadic, very infrequent, and mysterious problem that affects a few people.

My question is, what can I do as a work-around? This might work, if I call it before creating an EditorPane:

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(MyClass.class.getClassLoader());
```

But I don't really understand classloaders as well as I would like (and I've tried to understand them better). I feel that changing the contextClassLoader in the EDT could have bad ramifications.

Any ideas what I can do?

EDIT: I had some correspondence with someone who understands Java ClassLoaders well. It seems this is an obscure ClassLoader race condition. That is, a bug in Java.

Comment: Any chance to upgrade the user's Java runtime?

Comment: @Tamás, this is a Mac app. I asked him to try the latest Mac Java update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
```

If the code in `JEditorPane.registerEditorKitForContentType` does not check for a null return value in the above code, this is a bug in `JEditorPane`. Note that `MyClass.class.getClassLoader()` [may also return null](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader()). The only one you can rely on is the [system ClassLoader](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemClassLoader()).

The pattern for setting the context `ClassLoader` for an invocation usually looks something like this:

```
Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
ClassLoader old = thread.getContextClassLoader();
thread.setContextClassLoader(fooClassLoader);
try {
  // do call that depends on context ClassLoader
} finally {
  thread.setContextClassLoader(old);
}
```

The value that should be set via `setContextClassLoader` will depend on the intent of the code that is consuming it and the design of the `ClassLoader` framework you are running in.

In a stand-alone application, you can probably get away with just using this `ClassLoader` (passing in a ref to the current class):

```
private ClassLoader findClassLoaderForContext(Class<?> c) {
  ClassLoader context = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
  ClassLoader me = c.getClassLoader();
  ClassLoader system = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
  return (context == null) ? (me == null) ? system : me : context;
}
```

In a ClassLoader-sensitive plug-in framework (a Java EE server would be a prime example), it would pay to understand the nature and usage of the loading scheme.

Comment: I tried that pattern you gave for setting the context classloader for an invocation. I like it because it doesn't screw up things potentially for other uses of the contextclassloader.