# Class re-appears in a class loader after using embedded interpreter

Tags: swing, scala, classloader, interpreter

I am seeing an odd problem when using an embedded Scala interpreter. It manifests itself as a corruption (?) of the hosting (non-interpreter) class loader. It roughly goes like this:

- I have a class `Foo` in the hosting environment
- I am matching against `Foo` in some place (`case f: Foo => ...`)
- I am running the interpreter at some point (`IMain -> interpret`)
- After that the pattern match for `Foo` fails; if I check the class it is `Foo` but it does not match with `Foo`

So I except that there are now two competing class loaders which produce two non-identical instances of `class Foo`. There is *only one* `Foo` in my entire class path, so there is no way that it could be shadowed. Also, it is sufficient to run something like `1 + 1` in the interpreter, so there is absolutely no way that the `IMain` itself tried to load class `Foo`.

I know this is very vague, but I am hoping for hints as to trace the bug.

---

**Edit**: After further investigation, this problem occurs only when building against Scala 2.11.0, but disappears when building against 2.10.4; I ensured that the builds were made from clean-state. This worries me, because it could indicate a new problem with the 2.11 interpreter?

The class involved (`Foo` in the example) is a Java class, so there is also no reason to believe it was compiled against the wrong Scala version.

---

**Edit**: After further investigation, this problem might relate to Java Swing rather than the Scala interpreter. `Foo` is actually a `javax.swing.text.Document` sub-class, and I can see some problems with `JEditorPane` ([How can I safely solve this Java context classloader problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855808/how-can-i-safely-solve-this-java-context-classloader-problem)) and Swing threading (http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8017776). I am using OpenJDK 6 and OpenJDK 7, I believe OpenJDK 6 is a fork off OpenJDK 7, so it might still be the problem showing up in the Bug database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that in Scala 2.11.0, the interpreter sets the thread's context class loader but does not restore it to its previous value.

The following is a workaround:

```
val th = Thread.currentThread()
val cl = th.getContextClassLoader
try {
  intp.interpret(text)
} finally {
  th.setContextClassLoader(cl)
}
```